# On clicking an html table cell Make it editable with dropdown Box rather than textbox

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have a table and I made it editable, thats why its cells will become textbox on clicking each cell.
The code is

```
function changeContent(tablecell)
{
    tablecell.innerHTML = "<INPUT type=text name=newname onBlur=\"javascript:submitNewName(this);\" value=\""+tablecell.innerHTML+" \">";
    tablecell.firstChild.focus();
}
```

I would like to display a dropdown list instead of textbox. Also that drop down should have the options Daily and Monthly.

How can I do that?

Comment: It's better use jQuery for things like that. Spend your time and result will be great.

Comment: @sergzach I disagree with that. He needs a much better understanding of built in JS functions before starting to master JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static strings example:

```
function changeContent(tablecell)
{
var cellInner =  "<select name=\"newname\" onBlur=\"javascript:submitNewName(this);\">";
cellInner += "<option>" + tablecell.innerHTML + "</option>";
cellInner += "<option>Daily</option>";
cellInner += "<option>Monthly</option>";
cellInner += "</select>";

tablecell.innerHTML = cellInner;

tablecell.firstChild.focus();

}
```

But to be honest I do not like the static string approach. You would be better using the JS DOM functions.

Something like:

```
function changeContent(tablecell)
{
var dropDown = document.createElement("select");

//  Set attributes.
dropDown.name = "newname";
//.... etc

var option1 = document.createElement("option");
option1.innerHTML = tablecell.innerHTML;

var option2 = document.createElement("option");
option2.innerHTML = "Daily";

var option3 = document.createElement("option");
option3.innerHTML = "Monthly";

dropDown.appendChild(option1);
dropDown.appendChild(option2);
dropDown.appendChild(option3);

tablecell.innerHTML = "";
tablecell.appendChild(dropDown);
}
```

I haven't tested the code so there may be some syntax errors but the principle is correct

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeContent(tablecell)
{
    tablecell.innerHTML = "<SELECT><option name='daily'>Daily</option><option name='monthly'>Monthly</option></SELECT>";
}
```

The answer may be incomplete. In this case, please, detail it.